# Infinispan cache eviction using CLI

Tags: caching, jboss, command-line-interface, infinispan

I have a couple of entities for JBoss 7, where I set the caching as annotation like:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL, region = "USERS")
```

and time to time I need to evict (flush) this cache region. Prior JBoss 7 (Infinispan) I used an MBean what did this flushing. But now JBoss 7 is not the case, so I need a solution based on something what can be elaborated programatically (ex. CLI)

Does anybody know how to evict manually an Infinispan local cache using CLI?

I am using JBoss 7 in standalone mode and in jboss-cli, for the eviction operation there is no way to specify the region's name.

Any hint?

SK

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan doesn't have regions, you can only clear the entire cache.

On the other hand, Hibernate should create a separate Infinispan cache for each region.

Comment: Hi Dan, as you can see I set the region attribute for the Cache annotation but using CLI query I can not see any subset named USERS in the cache.  By the way, do you speak romania also?

Comment: I do speak Romanian, yes :) What caches do you see? You should have one cache for each region.